# Closed form for $\int_0^1\log\log\left(\frac{1}{x}+\sqrt{\frac{1}{x^2}-1}\right)\mathrm dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, logarithms, definite-integrals, closed-form

Please help me to find a closed form for the following integral:
$$\int_0^1\log\left(\log\left(\frac{1}{x}+\sqrt{\frac{1}{x^2}-1}\right)\right)\,{\mathrm d}x.$$

I was told it could be calculated in a closed form.

Comment: Do you have any idea of what could be done? Did the person that tell you there was a closed form hint you in any way? Don't you know what the result should be?

Comment: It may or may not help to realize $\log\left(\frac{1}{x} + \sqrt{\frac{1}{x^2} - 1}\right)$ as $\operatorname{arsech} x$. This isn't a hint, just an observation.

Comment: @Stahl I was thinking about that too.

Comment: @PeterTamaroff Unfortunately, no hints were given, except that the closed form is quite simple, although might be not elementary.

Comment: Here are some equivalent forms:  Since $\text{sech}^{-1}(x)=\log\left(\frac{1}{x}+\sqrt{\frac{1}{x^{2}}-1}\right),$ we are trying to evaluate $$\int_{0}^{1}\log\left(\text{sech}^{-1}(x)\right)dx.$$ Let $u=\text{sech}^{-1}x$  so that $x=\text{sech}(u)=\frac{1}{\cosh(u)}.$  Then $dx=d(\frac{1}{\cosh(u)})$ , and we are looking at $$-\int_{0}^{\infty}\log ud\left(\frac{1}{\cosh(u)}\right)$$  which equals $$\int_{0}^{\infty}\log u\frac{\sinh(u)}{\cosh(u)^{2}}du.$$ Using integration by parts, this becomes $$\lim_{a\rightarrow0}\left(\log a+\int_{a}^{\infty}\frac{\text{sech}(x)}{u}du\right).$$

Comment: It's not clear how to proceed from $$\int_{0}^{\infty}\log u\frac{\sinh(u)}{\cosh(u)^{2}}du,$$ although it is a rather nice form.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

$$\boxed{\displaystyle\int_0^1\log\log\left(\frac1x+\sqrt{\frac1{x^2}-1}\right)\mathrm dx=-\gamma-2\ln\frac{2\Gamma(3/4)}{\Gamma(1/4)}}\tag{$\heartsuit$}$$

---

**Derivation**:

After the change of variables $x=\frac{1}{\cosh u}$ the integral becomes
$$\int_0^{\infty}\ln u \frac{\sinh u}{\cosh^2 u}du,$$
as was noticed above by Eric. We would like to integrate by parts to kill the logarithm but we get two divergent pieces. To go around this, let us consider another integral,
$$I(s)=\int_0^{\infty}u^s \frac{\sinh u}{\cosh^2 u}du,$$
with $s>0$. The integral we actually want to compute is equal to $I'(0)$, which will be later obtained in the limit.

Indeed, integrating once by parts one finds that
\begin{align}
I(s)&=s\int_0^{\infty}\frac{u^{s-1}du}{\cosh u}=s\cdot 2^{1-2 s}\Gamma(s)\left[\zeta\left(s,\frac14\right)-\zeta\left(s,\frac34\right)\right]=\\ &=2^{1-2 s}\Gamma(s+1)\left[\zeta\left(s,\frac14\right)-\zeta\left(s,\frac34\right)\right],
\end{align}
where $\zeta(s,a)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+a)^{-s}$ denotes Hurwitz zeta function (in the way we have used its integral representaion (5) from [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HurwitzZetaFunction.html)).

Now to get ($\heartsuit$), it suffices to use
\begin{align}
&\frac{\partial}{\partial s}\left[2^{1-2 s}\Gamma(s+1)\right]_{s=0}=-2\gamma-4\ln 2,\\ 
&\zeta\left(0,\frac14\right)-\zeta\left(0,\frac34\right)=\frac12,
\\
&\frac{\partial}{\partial s}\left[\zeta\left(s,\frac14\right)-\zeta\left(s,\frac34\right)\right]_{s=0}=-\ln\frac{\Gamma(\frac34)}{\Gamma(\frac14)}.
\end{align}
[See formulas (10) and (16) on the [same page](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HurwitzZetaFunction.html)].

Comment: Beautiful answer ! +1 indeed. Cheers :)

Comment: Maybe this formula is better and shorter?
$$-\gamma - \ln {\frac {8 \pi ^ 2} {\Gamma (\frac {1} {4}) ^ 4 }}$$

Comment: @KvanTTT I guess it depends. In my research context, the ratio $ \Gamma(z) / \Gamma(1-z)$ appears very often - there is even a special notation $\gamma(z)$ for it.

Answer (score 26):

To find the integral
$$I=\int_{0}^{1}\ln{\left(\ln{\left(\dfrac{1}{x}+\sqrt{\dfrac{1}{x^2}-1}\right)}\right)}dx,$$
let $x=e^{-y}$ then
$$I=\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-y}\ln{\ln{\left(e^y+\sqrt{e^{2y}-1}\right)}}dy,$$
so
\begin{align*}
I&=\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-x} \ln{\left(\ln{\left(e^x+\sqrt{e^{2x}-1}\right)}\right)}dx, 
\quad \text{ let } y=\ln{\left(e^x+\sqrt{e^{2x}-1}\right)}\\
&=2\int_{0}^{\infty}\dfrac{e^y(e^{2y}-1)}{(1+e^{2y})^2}\ln{y}dy\\
&=2\int_{0}^{\infty}
\dfrac{e^{-y}(1-e^{-2y})}{(1+e^{-2y})^2}\ln{y}dy\\
&=2\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-y}(1-e^{-2y})
\left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1}ne^{-2y(n-1)}\right)\ln{y}dy\\
&=2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1}n
\int_{0}^{\infty}\left(e^{-y(2n-1)}-e^{-y(2n+1)}\right)\ln{y}dy\\
&=2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1}\cdot n\left(-\dfrac{\gamma+\ln{(2n-1)}}{2n-1}+\dfrac{\gamma+\ln{(2n+1)}}{2n+1}\right)\\
&=2\gamma\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^n\cdot n
\left(\dfrac{1}{2n-1}-\dfrac{1}{2n+1}\right)
+2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^n \cdot n
\left(\dfrac{\ln{(2n-1)}}{2n-1}-\dfrac{\ln{(2n+1)}}{2n+1}\right)\\
&=\gamma\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n
\left(\dfrac{2n}{2n-1}-\dfrac{2n}{2n+1}\right)
+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n
\left(\dfrac{2n\ln{(2n-1)}}{2n-1}
-\dfrac{2n\cdot\ln{(2n+1)}}{2n+1}\right)\\
&=\gamma\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n
\left(\dfrac{1}{2n-1}+\dfrac{1}{2n+1}\right) \\
&\qquad +\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n
\left(\dfrac{(2n-1+1)\ln{(2n-1)}}{2n-1}
-\dfrac{(2n+1-1)\ln{(2n+1)}}{2n+1}\right)\\
&=-\gamma+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n
\ln{\dfrac{2n-1}{2n+1}}
+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n
\left(\dfrac{\ln{(2n-1)}}{2n-1}+\dfrac{\ln{(2n+1)}}{2n+1}\right)\\
&=-\gamma+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n\ln{\dfrac{2n-1}{2n+1}}\\
&=-\gamma-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\ln{\dfrac{4n-3}{4n-1}}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\ln{\dfrac{4n-1}{4n+1}}\\
&=-\gamma+
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\ln{\dfrac{(n-1/4)^2}{(n-3/4)(n+1/4)}}\\
&=-\gamma+\lim_{N\to\infty}\ln{\left(
\frac{
\left[
\left(-\frac{1}{4}+1\right)\left(-\frac{1}{4}+2\right)
\cdots\left(-\frac{1}{4}+N\right)
\right]^2
}{
\left[
\left(-\frac{3}{4}+1\right)\left(-\frac{3}{4}+2\right)
\cdots \left(-\frac{3}{4}+N\right)
\right]
\left[
\left(\frac{1}{4}+1\right)\left(\frac{1}{4}+2\right)
\cdots\left(\frac{1}{4}+N\right)
\right]
}\right)}\\
&=-\gamma+\ln{\dfrac{-3\Gamma{(-3/4)}\Gamma{(1/4)}}{\Gamma^2{(-1/4)}}}\\
&=-\gamma+\ln{\dfrac{4\Gamma^2{(1/4)}}{\Gamma^2(-1/4)}}\\
&=-\gamma+4\ln{\Gamma{\left(\dfrac{1}{4}\right)}}-3\ln{2}-2\ln{\pi}
\end{align*}

Comment: Very nice! I upvoted.

Answer (score 2):

Following the comments above, there is another path with digamma function. Recalling this identity of Euler-Mascheroni constant

$$-\int_{0}^{\infty} {e^{-u}\ln u \>\mathrm{d}u} = \gamma$$

and

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}(e^{-u}\tanh u)}{\mathrm{d}u} = e^{-u} - \frac{\sinh u}{\cosh^{2}\!u}$$

We deduce

$$\begin{aligned}
I + \gamma 
& = \int_{0}^{\infty} {\left( \frac{\sinh u}{\cosh^{2}\!u}-e^{-u} \right)\ln u \>\mathrm{d}u}\\
& = -(e^{-u}\tanh u\ln u) \bigr|_{u=0}^{\infty} + \int_{0}^{\infty} {\frac{e^{-u}\tanh u}{u} \mathrm{d}u}\\
& = \int_{0}^{\infty} {\frac{e^{-u}\tanh u}{u} \mathrm{d}u}
\end{aligned}$$

Introduce a parameterized integral

$$J(a) = \int_{0}^{\infty} {\frac{e^{-au}\tanh u}{u} \mathrm{d}u}$$

Take derivative of $J(a)$

$$\begin{aligned}
\frac{\mathrm{d}J(a)}{\mathrm{d}a}
& = -\int_{0}^{\infty} {e^{-au}\tanh u \>\mathrm{d}u}\\
& = \int_{0}^{\infty} {e^{-au} \>\mathrm{d}u} - \int_{0}^{\infty} {e^{-au}(1+\tanh u) \>\mathrm{d}u}
\end{aligned}$$

where we have

$$\begin{aligned}
\int_{0}^{\infty} {e^{-au}(1+\tanh u) \>\mathrm{d}u}
& = 2\int_{0}^{\infty} {\frac{e^{-au}}{1+e^{-2u}} \mathrm{d}u}\\
& = 2\int_{0}^{\infty} {\frac{e^{-au}(1-e^{-2u})}{1-e^{-4u}} \mathrm{d}u}\\
& = \frac1{2} \int_{0}^{\infty} {\frac{e^{-\tfrac{a}{4}u}}{1-e^{-u}} \mathrm{d}u} - \frac1{2} \int_{0}^{\infty} {\frac{e^{-\tfrac{a+2}{4}u}}{1-e^{-u}} \mathrm{d}u}
\end{aligned}$$

Using the integral representation of digamma function

$$\psi(z) = \int_{0}^{\infty} {\left( \frac{e^{-u}}{u} - \frac{e^{-zu}}{1-e^{-u}} \right) \mathrm{d}u}$$

we have

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}J(a)}{\mathrm{d}a} = \frac1{a} + \frac1{2}\psi\bigg(\frac{a}{4}\bigg) - \frac1{2}\psi\left(\frac{a+2}{4}\right)$$

with $\lim_{a\to\infty}J(a)=0$ and $I+\gamma=J(1)$

$$\begin{aligned}
J(1) & = -\int_{1}^{\infty} {J'(a) \>\mathrm{d}a}\\
& = -\left( \ln a + 2\ln\Gamma\bigg(\frac{a}{4}\bigg) - 2\ln\Gamma\left(\frac{a+2}{4}\right) \right) \biggr|_{a=1}^{\infty}
\end{aligned}$$

Notice the asymptotic series of $\ln\Gamma(z) = (z-\tfrac1{2})\ln z - z + \ln2\pi + o(z^{-1})$ which indicates

$$\lim_{a\to\infty} {\left( \ln a + 2\ln\Gamma\bigg(\frac{a}{4}\bigg) - 2\ln\Gamma\left(\frac{a+2}{4}\right) \right)} = 2\ln2$$

thus

$$I + \gamma = -2\ln2 + 2\ln\frac{\Gamma(1/4)}{\Gamma(3/4)}$$

Recalling reflection formula, we can finally deduce

$$I = -\gamma - 3\ln2 - 2\ln\pi + 4\ln\Gamma\left(\frac1{4}\right)$$

---

*(Edit for another path)*

Occasionally, I find a direct solution which is almost equivalent to the method I used above, where let $\frac1{t} = \frac1{x} + \sqrt{\frac1{x^{2}}-1}$, which gives
$$
 x = \frac{2t}{1+t^{2}}, \quad \mathrm{d}x = -\frac{2(t^{2}-1)}{(t^{2}+1)^{2}} \mathrm{d}t
 $$
hence
$$
 \int_{0}^{1} {\ln \left(\ln \left(\frac1{x} + \sqrt{\frac1{x^{2}}-1} \right) \right) \mathrm{d}x} = -2\int_{0}^{1} {\frac{t^{2}-1}{(t^{2}+1)^{2}} \ln\left(\ln\left(\frac1{t}\right)\right) \mathrm{d}t}
 $$
on the other hand, with integration by parts
$$
 \begin{aligned}
 \int_{0}^{1} {\frac{t^{2}-1}{t^{2}+1} \frac{\mathrm{d}t}{\ln t}}
 & = \frac{t(t^{2}-1)}{t^{2}+1}\ln\left(\ln\left(\frac1{t}\right)\right)\biggr|_{t=0}^{1} - \int_{0}^{1} {\frac{t^{4}+4t^{2}-1}{(t^{2}+1)^{2}} \ln\left(\ln\left(\frac1{t}\right)\right) \mathrm{d}t}\\
 & = -\int_{0}^{1} {\ln\left(\ln\left(\frac1{t}\right)\right) \mathrm{d}t} - 2\int_{0}^{1} {\frac{t^{2}-1}{(t^{2}+1)^{2}} \ln\left(\ln\left(\frac1{t}\right)\right) \mathrm{d}t}
 \end{aligned}
 $$
thus
$$
 \int_{0}^{1} {\ln \left(\ln \left(\frac1{x} + \sqrt{\frac1{x^{2}}-1} \right) \right) \mathrm{d}x} = \int_{0}^{1} {\ln\left(\ln\left(\frac1{t}\right)\right) \mathrm{d}t} + \int_{0}^{1} {\frac{t^{2}-1}{t^{2}+1} \frac{\mathrm{d}t}{\ln t}}
 $$
the first item is literally $-\gamma$, the second can be find in this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/285130/prove-int-01-fract2-1t21-log-tdt-2-log-left-frac2-gamma-left), where, actually, the integral is cracked by similar fashion used in this post above.

Answer (score 1):

To calculate $$\int_0^1\log\left(\log\left(\frac{1}{x}+\sqrt{\frac{1}{x^2}-1}\right)\right)\,{\mathrm d}x.$$

let $x=e^y$ then

$$\int\limits_{0}^{+\infty }{e^{-x}\ln \ln \left( e^{x}+\sqrt{e^{2x}-1} \right)dx}=\int\limits_{0}^{+\infty }{e^{-x}\ln \left( \cosh ^{-1}e^{x} \right)dx}=\int\limits_{1}^{+\infty }{\frac{\ln \left( \cosh ^{-1}e^{x} \right)}{x^{2}}dx}$$

$$=\int\limits_{0}^{+\infty }{\frac{\sinh x\ln x}{\cosh ^{2}x}dx}$$

Consider
$$F\left( s \right)=\int\limits_{0}^{+\infty }{\frac{x^{s}\sinh x}{\cosh ^{2}x}dx}$$ and note that $$F'\left( 0 \right)=\int\limits_{0}^{+\infty }{\frac{\sinh x\ln x}{\cosh ^{2}x}dx}=\int\limits_{0}^{+\infty }{e^{-x}\ln \ln \left( e^{x}+\sqrt{e^{2x}-1} \right)dx}$$

then
$$F\left( s \right)=\int\limits_{0}^{+\infty }{\frac{x^{s}\sinh x}{\cosh ^{2}x}dx}=s\int\limits_{0}^{+\infty }{\frac{x^{s-1}}{\cosh x}dx}=2s\int\limits_{0}^{+\infty }{\frac{e^{-x}x^{s-1}}{1+e^{-2x}}dx}$$

$$=2s\int\limits_{0}^{+\infty }{e^{-x}x^{s-1}\sum\limits_{n=0}^{+\infty }{\left( -e^{-2x} \right)^{n}}dx=}2s\sum\limits_{n=0}^{+\infty }{\left( -1 \right)^{n}\int\limits_{0}^{+\infty }{e^{-x-2nx}x^{s-1}dx}}$$

$$=2s\Gamma \left( s \right)\sum\limits_{n=0}^{+\infty }{\frac{\left( -1 \right)^{n}}{\left( 1+2n \right)^{s}}}=2^{1-s}s\Gamma \left( s \right)\sum\limits_{n=0}^{+\infty }{\frac{\left( -1 \right)^{n}}{\left( \frac{1}{2}+n \right)^{s}}}$$

$$S=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{+\infty }{\frac{\left( -1 \right)^{n}}{\left( \frac{1}{2}+n \right)^{s}}}=\frac{\left( -1 \right)^{0}}{\left( \frac{1}{2}+0 \right)^{s}}+\frac{\left( -1 \right)^{1}}{\left( \frac{1}{2}+1 \right)^{s}}+\frac{\left( -1 \right)^{2}}{\left( \frac{1}{2}+2 \right)^{s}}+\frac{\left( -1 \right)^{3}}{\left( \frac{1}{2}+3 \right)^{s}}+\frac{\left( -1 \right)^{4}}{\left( \frac{1}{2}+4 \right)^{s}}+\frac{\left( -1 \right)^{5}}{\left( \frac{1}{2}+5 \right)^{s}}+...$$

$$=\left( \frac{1}{\left( \frac{1}{2} \right)^{s}}+\frac{1}{\left( \frac{1}{2}+2 \right)^{s}}+\frac{1}{\left( \frac{1}{2}+4 \right)^{s}}+... \right)-\left( \frac{1}{\left( \frac{1}{2}+1 \right)^{s}}+\frac{1}{\left( \frac{1}{2}+3 \right)^{s}}+\frac{1}{\left( \frac{1}{2}+5 \right)^{s}}+... \right)$$

$$=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{+\infty }{\frac{1}{\left( \frac{4n+1}{2} \right)^{s}}}-\sum\limits_{n=0}^{+\infty }{\frac{1}{\left( \frac{4n+3}{2} \right)^{s}}}=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{+\infty }{\frac{1}{\left( 2n+\frac{1}{2} \right)^{s}}}-\sum\limits_{n=0}^{+\infty }{\frac{1}{\left( 2n+\frac{3}{2} \right)^{s}}}$$

$$=\frac{1}{2^{s}}\sum\limits_{n=0}^{+\infty }{\frac{1}{\left( n+\frac{1}{4} \right)^{s}}}-\frac{1}{2^{s}}\sum\limits_{n=0}^{+\infty }{\frac{1}{\left( n+\frac{3}{4} \right)^{s}}}=\frac{1}{2^{s}}\left( \zeta \left( s,\frac{1}{4} \right)-\zeta \left( s,\frac{3}{4} \right) \right)$$

$$F\left( s \right)=2^{1-s}s\Gamma \left( s \right)\sum\limits_{n=0}^{+\infty }{\frac{\left( -1 \right)^{n}}{\left( \frac{1}{2}+n \right)^{s}}}=2^{1-2s}\Gamma \left( s+1 \right)\left( \zeta \left( s,\frac{1}{4} \right)-\zeta \left( s,\frac{3}{4} \right) \right)$$

$$=2^{1-2s}\Gamma \left( s+1 \right)\left( \zeta \left( s,\frac{1}{4} \right)-\zeta \left( s,\frac{3}{4} \right) \right)$$

$$F'\left( s \right)=\frac{d}{ds}2^{1-2s}\Gamma \left( s+1 \right)\left( \zeta \left( s,\frac{1}{4} \right)-\zeta \left( s,\frac{3}{4} \right) \right)$$

$$=\left( \zeta \left( s,\frac{1}{4} \right)-\zeta \left( s,\frac{3}{4} \right) \right)\frac{d}{ds}\left( 2^{1-2s}\Gamma \left( s+1 \right) \right)+2^{1-2s}\Gamma \left( s+1 \right)\frac{d}{ds}\left( \zeta \left( s,\frac{1}{4} \right)-\zeta \left( s,\frac{3}{4} \right) \right)$$

$$=2^{1-2s}\Gamma \left( s+1 \right)\left( \zeta \left( s,\frac{1}{4} \right)-\zeta \left( s,\frac{3}{4} \right) \right)\left( \psi ^{\left( 0 \right)}\left( s+1 \right)-2\log 2 \right)+2^{1-2s}\Gamma \left( s+1 \right)\frac{d}{ds}\left( \zeta \left( s,\frac{1}{4} \right)-\zeta \left( s,\frac{3}{4} \right) \right)$$

where $$\zeta \left( s,q \right)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{+\infty }{\frac{1}{\left( q+n \right)^{s}}}$$
$$\frac{d}{ds}\zeta \left( s,\frac{1}{4} \right)=\frac{d}{ds}\sum\limits_{n=0}^{+\infty }{\frac{1}{\left( n+\frac{1}{4} \right)^{s}}}=-\left( \frac{\log \left( \frac{1}{4} \right)}{\left( \frac{1}{4} \right)^{s}}+\frac{\log \left( 1+\frac{1}{4} \right)}{\left( 1+\frac{1}{4} \right)^{s}}+\frac{\log \left( 2+\frac{1}{4} \right)}{\left( 2+\frac{1}{4} \right)^{s}}+\frac{\log \left( 3+\frac{1}{4} \right)}{\left( 3+\frac{1}{4} \right)^{s}}+... \right)$$

$$\frac{d}{ds}\zeta \left( s,\frac{3}{4} \right)=\frac{d}{ds}\sum\limits_{n=0}^{+\infty }{\frac{1}{\left( n+\frac{3}{4} \right)^{s}}}=-\left( \frac{\log \left( \frac{3}{4} \right)}{\left( \frac{3}{4} \right)^{s}}+\frac{\log \left( 1+\frac{3}{4} \right)}{\left( 1+\frac{3}{4} \right)^{s}}+\frac{\log \left( 2+\frac{3}{4} \right)}{\left( 2+\frac{3}{4} \right)^{s}}+\frac{\log \left( 3+\frac{3}{4} \right)}{\left( 3+\frac{3}{4} \right)^{s}}+... \right)$$

$$F'\left( 0 \right)=2\Gamma \left( 1 \right)\left( \zeta \left( 0,\frac{1}{4} \right)-\zeta \left( 0,\frac{3}{4} \right) \right)\left( \psi ^{\left( 0 \right)}\left( 1 \right)-2\log 2 \right)+2\Gamma \left( 1 \right)\frac{d}{ds}\left( \zeta \left( s,\frac{1}{4} \right)-\zeta \left( s,\frac{3}{4} \right) \right)\left| _{s=0} \right.$$

$$F'\left( 0 \right)=-\left( \gamma +2\log 2 \right)+2\frac{d}{ds}\left( \zeta \left( s,\frac{1}{4} \right)-\zeta \left( s,\frac{3}{4} \right) \right)\left| _{s=0} \right.$$

$$=-\left( \gamma +2\log 2 \right)-2\log \left( \frac{\Gamma \left( \frac{3}{4} \right)}{\Gamma \left( \frac{1}{4} \right)} \right)=-\left( \gamma +2\log 2 \right)-2\log \left( \frac{\sqrt{2}\pi }{\Gamma ^{2}\left( \frac{1}{4} \right)} \right)$$

$$=-\gamma -3\log 2-2\log \pi +4\log \Gamma \left( \frac{1}{4} \right)$$

Done (:

Answer (score 0):

To calculate $$\int_0^1\log\left(\log\left(\frac{1}{x}+\sqrt{\frac{1}{x^2}-1}\right)\right)\,{\mathrm d}x.$$

let $x=e^y$ then

$$\displaystyle{\int\limits_0^\infty  {{e^{ - x}}\log \left( {\log \left( {{e^x} + \sqrt {{e^{2x}} - 1} } \right)} \right)dx}  = \mathop  = \limits^{\log \left( {{e^x} + \sqrt {{e^{2x}} - 1} } \right) = y}  = 2\int\limits_0^\infty  {\frac{{{e^y}\left( {{e^{2y}} - 1} \right)}}{{{{\left( {1 + {e^{2y}}} \right)}^2}}}\log \left( y \right)dy}  = }$$

$\displaystyle{ = 2\int\limits_0^\infty  {\frac{{{e^{ - y}}\left( {1 - {e^{ - 2y}}} \right)}}{{{{\left( {1 + {e^{ - 2y}}} \right)}^2}}}\log \left( y \right)dy}  = 2\int\limits_0^\infty  {{e^{ - y}}\left( {1 - {e^{ - 2y}}} \right)\left( {\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {{{\left( { - 1} \right)}^{n - 1}} \cdot n \cdot } {e^{ - 2y\left( {n - 1} \right)}}} \right)\log \left( y \right)dy}  = }$

$\displaystyle{ = 2\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {{{\left( { - 1} \right)}^{n - 1}} \cdot n \cdot \int\limits_0^\infty  {\left( {{e^{ - y\left( {2n - 1} \right)}} - {e^{ - y\left( {2n + 1} \right)}}} \right)\log \left( y \right)dy} }  = 2\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {{{\left( { - 1} \right)}^{n - 1}} \cdot n \cdot \left( { - \frac{{\gamma  + \log \left( {2n - 1} \right)}}{{2n - 1}} + \frac{{\gamma  + \log \left( {2n + 1} \right)}}{{2n + 1}}} \right)}  = }$

$\displaystyle{ = 2\gamma \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {{{\left( { - 1} \right)}^n} \cdot n \cdot \left( {\frac{1}{{2n - 1}} - \frac{1}{{2n + 1}}} \right)}  + 2\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {{{\left( { - 1} \right)}^n} \cdot n \cdot \left( {\frac{{\log \left( {2n - 1} \right)}}{{2n - 1}} - \frac{{\log \left( {2n + 1} \right)}}{{2n + 1}}} \right)}  = }$

$\displaystyle{ = \gamma \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {{{\left( { - 1} \right)}^n}\left( {\frac{{2n}}{{2n - 1}} - \frac{{2n}}{{2n + 1}}} \right)}  + \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {{{\left( { - 1} \right)}^n}\left( {\frac{{2n \cdot \log \left( {2n - 1} \right)}}{{2n - 1}} - \frac{{2n \cdot \log \left( {2n + 1} \right)}}{{2n + 1}}} \right)}  = }$

$$\displaystyle{ = \gamma \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {{{\left( { - 1} \right)}^n}\left( {\frac{1}{{2n - 1}} + \frac{1}{{2n + 1}}} \right)}  + \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {{{\left( { - 1} \right)}^n}\left( {\frac{{\left( {2n - 1 + 1} \right) \cdot \log \left( {2n - 1} \right)}}{{2n - 1}} - \frac{{\left( {2n + 1 - 1} \right) \cdot \log \left( {2n + 1} \right)}}{{2n + 1}}} \right)}  = }$$

$$\displaystyle{ =  - \gamma  + \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {{{\left( { - 1} \right)}^n}\log \frac{{2n - 1}}{{2n + 1}}}  + \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {{{\left( { - 1} \right)}^n}\left( {\frac{{\log \left( {2n - 1} \right)}}{{2n - 1}} + \frac{{\log \left( {2n + 1} \right)}}{{2n + 1}}} \right)}  =  - \gamma  + \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {{{\left( { - 1} \right)}^n}\log \frac{{2n - 1}}{{2n + 1}}}  = }$$

$$\displaystyle{ =  - \gamma  - \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\log \frac{{4n - 3}}{{4n - 1}}}  + \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\log \frac{{4n - 1}}{{4n + 1}}}  =  - \gamma  + \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\log \frac{{{{\left( {n - 1/4} \right)}^2}}}{{\left( {n - 3/4} \right)\left( {n + 1/4} \right)}}}  =  - \gamma  + \mathop {\lim }\limits_{N \to \infty } \sum\limits_{n = 1}^N {\log \frac{{{{\left( { - 1/4 + n} \right)}^2}}}{{\left( { - 3/4 + n} \right)\left( {1/4 + n} \right)}}}  = }$$

$$\displaystyle{ =  - \gamma  + \mathop {\lim }\limits_{N \to \infty } \log \frac{{{{\left( {\left( { - \frac{1}{4} + 1} \right)\left( { - \frac{1}{4} + 2} \right)\left( { - \frac{1}{4} + 3} \right)..\left( { - \frac{1}{4} + N} \right)} \right)}^2}}}{{\left( {\left( { - \frac{3}{4} + 1} \right)\left( { - \frac{3}{4} + 2} \right)..\left( { - \frac{3}{4} + N} \right)} \right)\left( {\left( {\frac{1}{4} + 1} \right)\left( {\frac{1}{4} + 2} \right)..\left( {\frac{1}{4} + N} \right)} \right)}} = }$$

$$\displaystyle{ =  - \gamma  + \mathop {\lim }\limits_{N \to \infty } \log \left( {{{\left( {\frac{{\left( { - \frac{1}{4}} \right)\left( { - \frac{1}{4} + 1} \right)..\left( { - \frac{1}{4} + N} \right)}}{{\left( { - \frac{1}{4}} \right){{\left( {N + 1} \right)}^{ - 1/4}} \cdot N!}}} \right)}^2}\frac{{\left( { - \frac{3}{4}} \right)\frac{1}{4}{{\left( {N + 1} \right)}^{ - 3/4}}{{\left( {N + 1} \right)}^{1/4}}{{\left( {N!} \right)}^2}}}{{\left( {\left( { - \frac{3}{4}} \right)\left( { - \frac{3}{4} + 1} \right)..\left( { - \frac{3}{4} + N} \right)} \right)\left( {\frac{1}{4}\left( {\frac{1}{4} + 1} \right)..\left( {\frac{1}{4} + N} \right)} \right)}}} \right) = }$$

$$\displaystyle{ =  - \gamma  + \log \frac{{ - 3 \cdot \Gamma \left( { - \frac{3}{4}} \right)\Gamma \left( {\frac{1}{4}} \right)}}{{{\Gamma ^2}\left( { - \frac{1}{4}} \right)}} =  - \gamma  + \log \frac{{4{\Gamma ^2}\left( {\frac{1}{4}} \right)}}{{{\Gamma ^2}\left( { - \frac{1}{4}} \right)}} =  - \gamma  + \log \frac{{{\Gamma ^2}\left( {\frac{1}{4}} \right)}}{{4 \cdot {\Gamma ^2}\left( {\frac{3}{4}} \right)}} =  - \gamma  + 2\log \frac{{\Gamma \left( {\frac{1}{4}} \right)}}{{2 \cdot \Gamma \left( {\frac{3}{4}} \right)}} = }$$

$$\displaystyle{ =  - \gamma  + 2\log \frac{{{\Gamma ^2}\left( {\frac{1}{4}} \right)}}{{2 \cdot \sqrt 2  \cdot \pi }} =  - \gamma  + 4\log \Gamma \left( {\frac{1}{4}} \right) - 3\log 2 - 2\log \pi }$$