# Trouble evaluating the sum involving logarithm

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, logarithms

I was trying to solve this problem: [Closed form for $\int_0^1\log\log\left(\frac{1}{x}+\sqrt{\frac{1}{x^2}-1}\right)\mathrm dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/390640/closed-form-for-int-01-log-log-left-frac1x-sqrt-frac1x2-1-right)

In the procedure I followed, I came across the following sum:
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{k-1}k\left(\frac{\ln(2k+1)}{2k+1}-\frac{\ln(2k-1)}{2k-1}\right)$$

I cannot think of any approaches which would help me in evaluating the sum.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I must confess that, taking into account the answers you received, I have a problem : the numerical evaluation of the sum shows a convergence to a value of $0.391594$.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Looks like we have a strongly oscillating sum here, I also agree with your observation.

Comment: @AlexR. Yes, this is what happens ! Thanks for supporting the old man ! Cheers :)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: Thanks for chipping in, I was about to lose hope in the procedure I followed for the linked problem. :)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I have been able to find the other's error: The partial sum's last summand diverges and they still drop it.

Comment: @AlexR. I totally agree ! You won by less than a couple of minutes ! Cheers :)

Comment: The series is convergent using the alternating series test:$$k\left(\frac{\ln(2k+1)}{2k+1}-\frac{\ln(2k-1)}{2k-1}\right) \sim \frac{\ln k}{2k}$$ as $k$ tends to $+\infty$.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Yeah, cheers :) Maybe you can look into the difference of the partial sums? Don't seem to see an easy way to show that it converges to $0$

Comment: @OlivierOloa The alternating series test doesn't work here because the summands are actually monotonically _increasing_ and divergent. The AST requires them to be monotonically _decreasing_ and _convergent_ to $0$.

Comment: @AlexR, the monotonicity finally comes when k is really great, no? There is a typo in my precedent comment (a sign to change).

Comment: @OlivierOloa At least one would have to quantize that and find that the bracket grows like $\ln(k)/k^2$.

Comment: @Alex Qualitatively, we are sure that this is the case, no?

Comment: @OlivierOloa Yup, it has to be, since we were able to show convergence anyways :)

Comment: @PranavArora I found something:
$$\lim_{m\to\infty} S_m = \ln\left(\frac{\Gamma(\frac14)}{2\Gamma(\frac34)}\right)$$

Comment: @AlexR: I think that's correct because the answer to the linked problem consists of that. Thank you for the help so far! :)

Comment: As for the terms, the Mean Value Theorem says that for some $\kappa\in(k-\frac12,k+\frac12)$, $$\begin{align} \frac{\log(2k+1)}{2k+1}-\frac{\log(2k-1)}{2k-1} &=\frac{1-\log(2\kappa)}{2\kappa^2}\\ &=\frac{1-\log(2k)}{2k^2} +O\left(\frac{\log(k)}{k^3}\right)\end{align}$$ Thus, $$k\left(\frac{\log(2k+1)}{2k+1}-\frac{\log(2k-1)}{2k-1}\right)=\frac{1-\log(2k)}{2k} +O\left(\frac{\log(k)}{k^2}\right)$$ which is the difference of two monotonic sequences tending to $0$ plus a summable sequence

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The terms of the series vanish so we will look only at the partial sums where $n$ is odd.
$$
\begin{align}
&\sum_{k=1}^\infty(-1)^{k-1}k\left(\frac{\log(2k+1)}{2k+1}-\frac{\log(2k-1)}{2k-1}\right)\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^{k-1}k\frac{\log(2k+1)}{2k+1}-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(-1)^k(k+1)\frac{\log(2k+1)}{2k+1}\right)\tag{1}\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left((-1)^{n-1}n\frac{\log(2n+1)}{2n+1}+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}(-1)^{k-1}\log(2k+1)\right)\tag{2}\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left((2n+1)\frac{\log(4n+3)}{4n+3}+\sum_{k=1}^{n}\log\left(\frac{4k-1}{4k+1}\right)\right)\tag{3}\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\log\left((4n+3)^{\frac{2n+1}{4n+3}}\cdot\prod_{k=1}^{n}\frac{k-\frac14}{k+\frac14}\right)\tag{4}\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\log\left(2\sqrt{n}\frac{\Gamma(n+\frac34)}{\Gamma(\frac34)}\frac{\Gamma(\frac54)}{\Gamma(n+\frac54)}\right)\tag{5}\\
&=\log\left(2\frac{\Gamma(\frac54)}{\Gamma(\frac34)}\right)\tag{6}\\
&=\log\left(\frac12\frac{\Gamma(\frac14)}{\Gamma(\frac34)}\right)\tag{7}\\
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(1)$: write series as the limit of the partial sums, split into two sums, reindex the second sum
$(2)$: recombine the two sums
$(3)$: substitute $n\mapsto2n+1$ and combine pairs of terms of the sum
$(4)$: write a sum of logs as a log of a product
$(5)$: $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac1{2\sqrt{n}}(4n+3)^{\frac{2n+1}{4n+3}}=1$, write the product as a ratio of Gamma functions
$(6)$: Gautschi's inequality
$(7)$: $x\Gamma(x)=\Gamma(x+1)$

Answer (score 2):

As said in comments, the sum oscillates between two values and converges to the value $0.391594$.

If we expand in the same spirit as Larsen, what we can see is that $$F(n)=\sum_{k=1}^{n} (-1)^{k-1}k\left(\frac{\ln(2k+1)}{2k+1}-\frac{\ln(2k-1)}{2k-1}\right)$$ can be written as $$F(n)=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} (-1)^{k-1}\log(2k+1)-\frac{(-1)^n n \log(2n+1)}{2n+1}$$

**Added after AlexR's answer and comments**

Let us consider the last term in AlexR' answer
$$\Delta = (m+1) \left(\frac1{2m+3} \ln(2m+3) - \frac1{2m+1} \ln(2m+1)\right) $$ and let us expand it as a Taylor series for large values of $m$. We so obtain $$\Delta =\frac{\log \left(\frac{1}{m}\right)+1-\log (2)}{2 m}+\frac{-\log
   \left(\frac{1}{m}\right)-2+\log (2)}{2
   m^2}+O\left(\left(\frac{1}{m}\right)^3\right)$$

Comment: Found a nice estimate-based approach to circumvent Taylor ;)
Maybe Taylor will be useful in finding the limit (Think of $S_m$ expanded at $m = \infty$)... (+1)

Comment: Be sure it is for me a real pleasure to work this problem at the same time as you. Sinergy has been proven (if required). Thank you.

Comment: Happy to work with you as well. I proceeded to find the limit using my partial sums: W|A finally found something
$$\lim_{m\to\infty} S_m = \ln\left(\frac{\Gamma(\frac14)}{2\Gamma(\frac34)}\right)$$
:-)

Comment: @AlexR. This is just great ! Congratulations !

Answer (score 1):

**On the limit**
Experimenting a bit I find
$$\lim_{m\to\infty} S_m = \ln\left(\frac{\Gamma(\frac14)}{2\Gamma(\frac34)}\right) = 0.391594392706836...$$
To be [the exact limit](http://www.wolframalpha.com/share/clip?f=d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427ecnupb76f26)

**On convergence**
Let $a_k := \frac{\ln(2k-1)}{2k-1}$ then
$$\begin{align*}
S_m & = \sum_{k=1}^m  (-1)^{k-1} k (a_{k+1} - a_k) \\
& = \sum_{k=2}^{m+1} (-1)^k (k-1) a_k + \sum_{k=1}^m (-1)^k k a_k \\
& \stackrel{a_1 = 0}= \sum_{k=2}^m (-1)^k ((k-1) a_k + k a_k) + (-1)^{m+1} ma_{m+1} \\
& = \sum_{k=2}^m (-1)^k \ln(2k-1) + (-1)^{m+1} \frac{m}{2m+1} \ln(2m+1)
\end{align*}$$
The problem all answerers overlooked is the factor of the last summand not being $\frac1{2m+1}$ but $\frac{m}{2m+1}$.

---

Let's first try to prove that the sequence is cauchy:
$$\begin{align*}
|S_{m+1}-S_m| & = |(-1)^{m+1} \ln(2m+1) \\
&\left. \qquad + (-1)^m \frac{m+1}{2m+3} \ln(2m+3) - (-1)^{m+1} \frac m{2m+1} \ln(2m+1) \right| \\
& = \left| (m+1) \left(\frac1{2m+3} \ln(2m+3) - \frac1{2m+1} \ln(2m+1)\right) \right| \\
& \le (m+1) \ln(2m+3) \left(\frac1{2m+1} - \frac1{2m+3}\right) \\
& = \ln(2m+3) (m+1) \frac2{4m(m+2) + 3} \\
& \le \ln(2m+3) \frac1{2m} \to 0 & (m\to\infty)
\end{align*}$$

This proves convergence. The actual value seems a tad bit harder to prove.