# Proving that $\int_{0}^{1}\ln^{2n}\left(\ln\left({1-\sqrt{1-x^2}\over x}\right)\over \ln\left({1+\sqrt{1-x^2}\over x}\right)\right)dx=(-\pi^2)^n$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I was observing [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/390640/closed-form-for-int-01-log-log-left-frac1x-sqrt-frac1x2-1-right) and was able to conjecture
$$\int_{0}^{1}\ln^{2n}\left(\ln\left({1-\sqrt{1-x^2}\over x}\right)\over \ln\left({1+\sqrt{1-x^2}\over x}\right)\right)\mathrm dx=(-\pi^2)^n\tag1$$
Where $n\ge1$.

**Making an attempt:**
$$x=\sin u \implies dx=\cos udu$$
$$\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\ln^{2n}\left(\ln\left({1-\cos u\over \sin u}\right)\over \ln\left({1+\cos u\over \sin u}\right)\right)\cos u\,du\tag2$$
simplify further to
$$\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\ln^{2n}\left(\ln\tan\left({u\over 2}\right)\over \ln\cot\left({u\over 2}\right)\right)\cos u\,du\tag3$$
$$\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\ln^{2n}(-1)\cos u\,du\tag4$$
This is not making any sense here!

**How can we prove $(1)?$**

Comment: Why is that not making any sense?

Comment: $ln(-1)$, this is not possible

Comment: You **conjectured** $(1)$? How?

Comment: Since $$ \frac{x}{1-\sqrt{1-x^2}} =  \frac{x}{1-\sqrt{1-x^2}}  \frac{1+\sqrt{1-x^2}}{1+\sqrt{1-x^2}} = \frac{x(1+\sqrt{1-x^2})}{x^2} = \frac{1+\sqrt{1-x^2}}{x}  $$, the argument of the log is always negative. Moreover, it's constant, since it's of the form $\log{u}/(\log{1/u}) = -1$. You can see this even without substituting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the principal value of $\ln(-1)$ is $i\pi$:
$$\int_0^{\pi/2}\ln^{2n}(-1)\cos u\,du$$
$$=\int_0^{\pi/2}(i\pi)^{2n}\cos u\,du$$
$$=(i\pi)^{2n}\int_0^{\pi/2}\cos u\,du$$
$$=(i\pi)^{2n}=(-\pi^2)^n$$
However, as the complex logarithm is multivalued, this answer is not well-defined (as mentioned by Chappers in the comments).

Comment: $ln(-1)=i\pi$ that is very new to me, thank you so much.

Comment: @Latte' This relies on Euler's identity $e^{i\pi}=-1$.

Comment: The obvious is not so obvious after all!

Comment: The integrand isn't real. The argument of log of the numerator is negative.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that the logarithm of $-1$ can equally well be chosen as $-i\pi$. Or $(2k+1)i\pi$ for any integer $k$, since $e^{2k\pi i}=1$. For numbers that are not positive reals, there is no canonical choice of logarithm without imposing some sort of continuity condition, and one cannot impose such a condition over the whole complex plane, even if we exclude zero.

Comment: @Chappers I used principal value here. Would I have to make any further steps to justify the integral and this choice?

Comment: Since the argument's the constant $-1$, there isn't any way to tell what the OP was intending (especially since they are not familiar with the logarithm of negative numbers; I suspect computer algebra software was involved in the evaluation somewhere...). But in any case, I do think it's also important to point out why the answer is not really well-defined in addition to explaining where the $-\pi^2$ comes from.

Comment: Wolfram alpha always assumes that $\log$ is the principal logarithm. When dealing with real integrals we always assume the principal logarithm.