# How prove this integral $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{(x-1)dx}{(x+1)\ln{x}}=\ln{\frac{\pi}{2}}$

Tags: integration

show that
$$I=\int_{0}^{1}\dfrac{(x-1)dx}{(x+1)\ln{x}}=\ln{\left(\dfrac{\pi}{2}\right)}$$

I say this integral background,today I have use this [wolf](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cint_%7B0%7D%5E%7B1%7D%28x-1%29%2F%28%28x%2B1%29lnx%29dx) play some function,and
Suddenly I found this interesting problem

I try solve this by hand,

$$\dfrac{x-1}{(x+1)\ln{x}}=(1-\dfrac{2}{x+1})\dfrac{1}{\ln{x}}$$
then It's ugly
then
$$I=\int_{0}^{1}\dfrac{1}{\ln{x}}dx-\int_{0}^{1}\dfrac{2}{\ln{x}}d\ln{(1+x)}$$

Comment: Perhaps "Differentiation Under the Integral Sign" would help here? My idea is to let $I(a)=\int_0^1\dfrac{x^a-1}{(x+1)\ln x}\operatorname d\!x$ and then try to compute $I'(a)$.

Comment: See this answer: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/280105/evaluating-int-01-frac1-x1x-frac-mathrm-dx-ln-x/280134#280134

Comment: Oh,Thank you very much! @RonGordon

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have:
$$ I = \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{1-e^{-x}}{1+e^{x}}\frac{dx}{x} = \int_{0}^{+\infty}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{1-e^{-x}}{1+e^{x}}e^{-tx}\,dt\,dx$$
So:
$$ I = \frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\left(-H_{(t-1)/2}+2H_{t/2}-H_{(t+1)/2}\right)\,dt = \frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{1}\left(H_{t/2}-H_{(t-1)/2}\right)\,dt.$$
Once one proves that:
$$\int_{0}^{1/2}H_t\,dt = \frac{1}{2}\left(\gamma+\log\frac{\pi}{4}\right),$$
$$\int_{-1/2}^{0}H_t\,dt = \frac{1}{2}\left(\gamma-\log\pi\right),$$
the result follows. The previous identities are equivalent to:
$$2\int_{0}^{1/2}\psi(t+1)\,dt = \log\frac{\pi}{4},$$
$$2\int_{-1/2}^{0}\psi(t+1)\,dt = -\log\pi,$$
but since $\psi=\frac{d}{dz}\log\Gamma(z)$, we have:
$$\int_{0}^{1/2}\psi(t+1)\,dt = \log\Gamma\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)-\log\Gamma\left(1\right),$$
$$\int_{-1/2}^{0}\psi(t+1)\,dt = \log\Gamma(1)-\log\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}\right),$$
and we are done.